# How to make KeyListener accept input from Robot

Tags: java, jframe, keylistener, keyevent

The main purpose of this code is a sort of AutoHotKey that uses keyListeners in JFrame. AutoHotKey is much easier to use and would provide a quicker solution but I am writing this for learning purposes

I am trying to make one of my keyListeners (KeyPressed) take input from a robot keyPress instead of the users keyPress. I have created a Robot object and sent out the keyPress and keyRelease but the program still is asking for another input from the user.

What I want to happen is for the keyPress event to be fired and the keyListener to take that as the input from the user and continue on with the rest of the program which will eventually close it.

Current Code:

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7225065896901900132L;

/**
 * Aye, I do not recommend storing passwords as plain text if it is for
 * something important but here is this code anyway because i'm bored.
 * 
 * Also should not that using a AutoHotKey or any other macro program is way
 * easier but i'm using Java because learning amiright
 */

//declaring variables and objects
private static String fileName = "C:/users/21cra/Desktop/rmtinfo.txt";
private static Scanner SC;
private Robot robObject;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //creates JFrame
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Main frame = new Main();
            frame.setTitle("Copier");
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setSize(0, 0);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}

public Main() {

    //add key listener for this JFrame
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

    // try catch for forcing Escape key press
    try {
        robObject = new Robot();
        robObject.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
        robObject.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
        System.out.println("press");
    } catch (AWTException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    // declaring variables and objects
    String pass = null;
    File passFile = new File(fileName);

    // try catch for handling next key press
    // also copies the first line of any file

    try {
        SC = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        pass = SC.next();

        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {

            StringSelection stringObj = new StringSelection(pass);
            Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            clipboard.setContents(stringObj, null);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println(pass);

    } catch (Exception error) {

        System.out.println("Error " + error);

    }

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}
```

}

Comment: `KeyListener` will need the component it is registered to have focus and be focusable. `JFrame` is a component component, so it's possible for different layers to "steal" focus, making it difficult to use. In your example, you're attempting to send key strokes before the window is realised and active, so you might consider using a second thread to send the key strokes

Comment: @MadProgrammer How would one go about creating a second thread for this issue? I am not to familiar with that concept and am still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are a number of issues.  In order for a `KeyListener` to generate key events, the component it is registered to MUST be focusable AND have keyboard focus.  This is a difficult thing to manage at the best of times.

You are generating key events BEFORE the window is realised (attached to a native peer) and visible on the screen, this means the `KeyListener` isn't going to be able to respond to them.  You need to wait till the window is visible and active on the screen.  Since `setVisible` simply states that the window "should" be made visible, there is no guarantee that the window will be active and available for processing input events.  You need some way to stage a delay between `setVisible` and the generation of the key strokes.

This is where something like a second `Thread` might be useful...

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        // try catch for forcing Escape key press
        try {
            Robot robObject = new Robot();
            robObject.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
            robObject.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
            System.out.println("press");
        } catch (AWTException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
t.start();
```

See [Concurrency in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) for more details.

So, really basic.  It starts a thread, waits one second and them triggers the key events.  It's a little dirty by should get the job done.

*nb: Swing is single threaded and not thread safe. Never update the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread*

Because `KeyListener` is such ... annoying, a better solution might be to make use of the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), this will give you better control over which focus levels the key events should be generated.

Maybe something more like...

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7225065896901900132L;

    /**
     * Aye, I do not recommend storing passwords as plain text if it is for
     * something important but here is this code anyway because i'm bored.
     *
     * Also should not that using a AutoHotKey or any other macro program is way
     * easier but im using Java because learning amiright
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Main frame = new Main();
                frame.setTitle("Copier");
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setSize(100, 100);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                        // try catch for forcing Escape key press
                        try {
                            Robot robObject = new Robot();
                            robObject.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
                            robObject.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
                            System.out.println("press");
                        } catch (AWTException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public Main() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = panel.getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "escape");
        actionMap.put("escape", new EscapeAction());

        setContentPane(panel);
    }

    protected class EscapeAction extends AbstractAction {

        private final String fileName = "C:/users/21cra/Desktop/rmtinfo.txt";

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String pass = null;
            File passFile = new File(fileName);
            try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {
                pass = scanner.next();

                StringSelection stringObj = new StringSelection(pass);
                Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                clipboard.setContents(stringObj, null);
                System.exit(0);

                System.out.println(pass);

            } catch (Exception error) {

                System.out.println("Error " + error);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Works perfectly =). Never thought about any extra APIs but it seems simple enough and works well. Thanks!